# How to get Company Credits using PHP IMDb Scraper API?

Tags: php, regex

How to get **Production Co**: on **Company Credits**?

```
<h3 class="subheading">Company Credits</h3>
<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Production Co:</h4>
    <span itemprop="creator">
        <a href="company" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Inflatable Film</span></a>
    </span>,
    <span itemprop="creator">
        <a href="company" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">True Productions</span></a>
    </span>
        <a href="companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co" itemprop='url'>See more</a>&nbsp;&raquo;
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use this code but it's not working:

```
$arr['production_co'] = $this->match('/Production Co:<\/h4>.*?<div class="info-content">(.*?)(<a|<\/div)/ms', $html, 1);
```

Please help me to get Production Co.

I'm using **PHP IMDb Scraper API**

here my imdbclass https://jadwal21.my.id/imdbclass.txt

here the grab.txt https://jadwal21.my.id/grab.txt

Comment: I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Are you sure that IMDB provides production Co in $html?

Comment: I dont know.. Im just get from view source... view-source:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3531176/

Comment: hmm..it seems its available.

Comment: please help me to fixed...

Comment: ok. I am looking this.

Comment: please check my grab.txt.. maybe I have wrong on grab.txt

Comment: @AdeevaAmeera Try this: `$arr['production_co'] = $this->match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', $this->match('/Production Co:(.*?)(<\/div>|See more)/ms', $html, 1), 1);`

Comment: in grab.txt Im use this 

add_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpwm_production_co', $movie_data['production_co'] );

Comment: `add_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpwm_production_co', $movie_data['production_co'] );`

`'post_content'  => ' '.$movie_data['production_co'].'  ',`
    
il try grab but not working.. he says  **Array** on post    
im use to wordpress